# Links between points in leaflet

Tags: r, visualization, r-leaflet

I have html file with map built in leaflet R`s package. One of layer contains points

[image: one]

 I need to visualize a links between points after clicking of any icon from group.

[image: two]

Does anyone has any idea how I can do that?

Comment: What is the logic to connect the points? Also it'll be impossible to help without a reproducible example. Consider adding one to your post.

Comment: The logic is defined by external source. I define this relationship and it is static.